# Oracle SQLPLUS AVG function when using a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, average

For a performance report on 4 servers I want to get an AVG per server per period, in this case 1 minute. I can get the COUNT and MAX but not the AVG(stay) per server. Each server is identified by the column CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, with the values 0,1,2 or 3. What do I do wrong in my query?

Thanks for your help.

**The output looks like this:**

```
                     Overall                                           server_1                server_2                server_3                server_4 
                                   Max     Avg                                  Max    Avg              Max    Avg              Max    Avg              Max    Avg
End Time             TXN   TPS    Stay    Stay   Appr   Decl Other       TXN   Stay   Stay       TXN   Stay   Stay       TXN   Stay   Stay       TXN   Stay   Stay
---------------- ------- ----- ------- ------- ------ ------ ----- --------- ------ ------ --------- ------ ------ --------- ------ ------ --------- ------ ------
2018-12-10 16:40    2354    39     513      74   1345   1008     1       599    316     11       559     48      7       599    513     29       597    328     28
```

**This is the query used:**

```
ACCEPT start_time CHAR PROMPT 'Enter start time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm): '
ACCEPT stop_time CHAR PROMPT 'Enter end time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm)  : '

DEFINE time_diff = 1

SELECT TO_CHAR((MIN(end_time)+(&time_diff/24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') c1, COUNT(*) c2,
       COUNT(*)/60 c3,
       MAX(stay) c4, ROUND(AVG(stay)) c5,
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(TXN.RES_CODE,1,3) = 'APP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c10,
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(TXN.RES_CODE,1,3) = 'DEC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c11,
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RES_CODE,1,3) <> 'APP' AND SUBSTR(RES_CODE,1,3) <> 'DEC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c12,
/*server_1*/
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c13,
       MAX (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 0 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c20,
       AVG (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 0 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c21, 
/*server_2*/
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c14,
       MAX (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 1 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c20,
       AVG (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 1 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c21,
/*server_3*/
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c15,
       MAX (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 2 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c20,
       AVG (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 2 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c21, 
/*server_4*/
       SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c16,
       MAX (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 3 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c20
       AVG (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) = 3 THEN stay ELSE 0 END) c21  
FROM txn
WHERE txn_origin_id NOT IN (2,3)
  AND end_time >= '&start_time'
  AND end_time  < '&stop_time'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the average"? What happens when you try? Syntax error? Runtime error? No error thrown, but the result is wrong? What else?

Comment: What is the data type of stay? and does stay contains NULLS?

Comment: In any case: the `ELSE 0` part of your `CASE` expressions is probably the problem; it doesn't affect `SUM` or `MAX` (perhaps), but it should definitely affect `COUNT` even if you don't seem to think so. Leave out `ELSE 0` (then the default will kick in, which is `ELSE NULL`, and is the correct thing).

Comment: @mathguy, the result of the AVG per server, per minute is not the same in this script as when I make a query which only selects data from one server at a time. The data from MAX and SUM are correct

Comment: @vivek the data type of STAY is NOT NULL NUMBER(9).

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, you're correct! After I removed the ELSE 0 the correct AVG is displayed/calculated. Only when there is no data at all for a server there is nothing displayed in the column, not even 0. But that's not a big issue. Thanks for your quick support!

Comment: @EdwinNieuwpoort - if you want to show 0 instead of NULL, you can use NVL - as a wrapper applied AFTER the average is calculated. But I would only do that if really needed - for example if it is needed in a further calculation, and the assumption that "NULL is the same as ZERO" is in fact valid - often it is not.

Answer (score 0):

As per my assumption, you are getting wrong AVG due to `ELSE 0` part.
Try using:

```
ROUND(AVG((CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CREATE_APP_LOC_ID, 1, 1) in (0,1,2,3) THEN stay ELSE 0 END))) c5,
```

instead of

```
ROUND(AVG(stay)) c5,
```

Comment: As per **your** assumption? I am seeing that pointed out in the comments below the original post, and I don't see **you** making that point. Shame on you.